# Flask-social login fails to redirect after login

Tags: python, facebook, redirect, flask, social-networking

I want to use Flask-Social to provide facebook only login. I use standard models provided with flask-social-example. On github I found this method:

```
@login_failed.connect_via(app)
def on_login_failed(sender, provider, oauth_response):
    connection_values = get_connection_values_from_oauth_response(provider, oauth_response)
    ds = current_app.security.datastore
    password = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(10)])
    full_name = connection_values['full_name']
    role = Role.query.filter_by(name='virtual').first()
    user = ds.create_user(
        full_name=full_name,
        password=encrypt_password(password))
    ds.add_role_to_user(user, role)
    ds.commit()
    connection_values['user_id'] = user.id
    connect_handler(connection_values, provider)
    login_user(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I am able to create users with that, and later log in without problems, but on first try it fails to redirect. I found open issue on github but it is yet to be resolved [Improper redirect #56](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social/issues/56).

If its library's fault, what is currently the best way to implement this in Flask? I want to be able to have 'virtual' users logging in only with facebook/twitter etc. and local users that can link their accounts to oauth profiles.